# Express in terms of $u+iv$

Tags: complex-numbers

$$z^{-2}$$

I guess the tricky part of this one is whether or not I am allowed to multiply by the complex conjugate raised to the power of 2. Is my attempt valid?

$$\frac{1}{(x+iy)^2}\cdot\frac{(x-iy)^2}{(x-iy)^2}$$

Comment: Backslash, not forwardslash.

Comment: And no.  You can always multiply by $1$ or add $0$.  But you can't multiply by $$\frac{1}{(x-iy)^2}\ne 1$$

Comment: @Bye_World oh...my fault. I didn't write the numerator. Editing now.

Comment: Then yes.  You can certainly multiply by $$\frac{(x-iy)^2}{(x-iy)^2}$$ because it's really just a complicated looking $1$.  In fact I'd say that it's even a very good idea to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $z= x+ iy$, then
$$ \frac{1}{z^2} = \frac{1}{(x+iy)^2} = \frac{1}{x^2 -y^2 + 2ixy} =\frac{1}{x^2 -y^2 + 2ixy} \frac{x^2 -y^2 - 2ixy}{x^2 -y^2 - 2ixy} = \frac{ x^2 -y^2 - 2ixy}{(x^2-y^2)^2 + 4x^2 y^2} $$
Then you may simplify the expression by expanding the bottom to see
$$ \frac{1}{z^2} = \frac{ x^2-y^2 } { (x^2 +y^2 )^2 } + i \frac{ 2xy } { (x^2+y^2)^2} = u + iv$$

Comment: You don't even need to expand the denominator out. You could just notice that the complex conjugate of $(x+iy)^2$ is $(x-iy)^2$ and multiply the top and bottom by that.

Comment: @ASKASK yea...that's what I meant to write but I totally goof'd. So then that is a totally valid complex conjugate?

Comment: Yeah it is. Think of the complex conjugate as just being a number you multiply by in order to end at a real number. Then $(x+iy)^2(x-iy)^2=((x+iy)(x-iy))^2=(x^2+y^2)^2$

Comment: @ASKASK btw, what is the point to doing this? We are learning this section but honestly we are just separating the real and imaginary parts to a complex number and saying that $u=Re(z)$ and $v=Im(z)$ (without the $i$). What is the point of the $u+iv$?